# Index Formula make row_num a relative reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I'm trying to get an index formula to copy down a column however when it does the row_numm wont change for example it should be.

```
=INDEX('Tracker Sheet'!$A:$A,3)
=INDEX('Tracker Sheet'!$A:$A,4)
=INDEX('Tracker Sheet'!$A:$A,5)
=INDEX('Tracker Sheet'!$A:$A,6)
```

however right now its just staying as

```
=INDEX('Tracker Sheet'!$A:$A,3)
=INDEX('Tracker Sheet'!$A:$A,3)
=INDEX('Tracker Sheet'!$A:$A,3)
=INDEX('Tracker Sheet'!$A:$A,3)
```

any help would be great

Comment: Problem solved with below answers or still need help?

Comment: Thanks both answers solved it. I did think there must be a way of changing the row_numm to a constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROW()`

```
=INDEX('Tracker Sheet'!$A:$A,ROW())
=INDEX('Tracker Sheet'!$A:$A,ROW())
=INDEX('Tracker Sheet'!$A:$A,ROW())
=INDEX('Tracker Sheet'!$A:$A,ROW())
```

Comment: FWIW OP may need to add a constant to the `ROW()` if the formula does not start in Row 3.  If it starts in Row 1 it would need to be `ROW() + 2`.  Just an FYI to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
=INDEX('Tracker Sheet'!$A:$A,ROW(A3),columnref)
```

Although the INDEX is redundant in this formula and you would just use:

```
=A3
```

Comment: What you are missing is a previous question by the OP, where he deletes lines on a regular basis and therefore any static cell reference return `#REF` when that row gets deleted.  By using INDEX and a constant or `ROW()` without a cell reference if rows get deleted then it will always refer to the correct line.

Comment: @ScottCraner Ah I took the question at face value. That would certainly affect the solution.